# Add formula to last column in table

Tags: excel, vba, datatable

I am looking for a way to add a formula to the last column of my existing table.

The sheet name is: "Bijna afgerond"
The table name is: "TEST_RANGE"

The formula must look up two columns and subtract.

I've the following code:

```vb
Sub Calculate()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim sFormula As String

    Set tbl = Sheets("Bijna afgerond").ListObjects("TEST_RANGE")

    sFormula = "=[@[Som van Aantal verwacht]]-[@[Som van Aantal ontvangen2]]"

    tbl.ListColumns("Percentage voltooid").DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Formula = sFormula

End Sub
```

During execution I got:

> Error 1004: Application or Object Defined Error

on the line:

```
tbl.ListColumns("Percentage voltooid").DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Formula = sFormula
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with that code?

Comment: sorry I forgot! error 9 during execution:

The subscript is out of range

Comment: Which line?  That error typically means "there's not a thing with that name" - could be the worksheet, listobject, or column name that's the problem.

Comment: the error was on the line: tbl.ListColumns("Percentage voltooid").DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Formula = sFormula

Comment: Then there's no column with that name?

Comment: yess there is ,the last column of my table has the name Percentage voltooid.

Comment: I changed the column name to xxx and that worked. But now i get another error: Error 1004 During Execution: Application or Object Defined Error

Comment: *On which line* ?  Can you paste that exact formula manually without any error?

Comment: I've found the solution. Excel doesn't like the blank spaces in the headers. so i've replaced  =[@[Som van Aantal verwacht]]-[@[Som van Aantal ontvangen2]] with =[@[Som_van_Aantal_verwacht]]-[@[Som_van_Aantal_ontvangen2]]

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't like the spaces in the names of the table headers.

I changed

```
sFormula = "=[@[Som van Aantal verwacht]]-[@[Som van Aantal
ontvangen2]]"
```

to

```
sFormula = "=[@[Som_van_Aantal_verwacht]]-[@[Som_van_Aantal_ontvangen2]]"
```

The full working code:

```vb
Sub CalculateTotalHours()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim sFormula As String

    Set tbl = Sheets("Bijna_afgerond").ListObjects("TEST_RANGE")

    sFormula = "=[@[Som_van_Aantal_verwacht]]-[@[Som_van_Aantal_ontvangen2]]"

    tbl.ListColumns("Bijna_afgerond").DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Formula = sFormula

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI there should be no problem with spaces in field names - works fine for me here.  I stand by my original guess about "bad spaces"...

Comment: don't understand what you mean. it was the solution for me

Comment: What I mean is that when you say "excel doesn't like the spaces in the names of the tableheaders", you're suggesting table headers can't have spaces.  I'm just clarifying for anyone coming along later to your post that table headers *can* have spaces.  Excel didn't like your *specific* spaces.

Comment: and how would you resolve my problem because I can't have spaces???

Comment: You can have spaces is what I'm saying - there was some *specific* problem with the original text in your table column headers though I have no way of knowing what that was.